# Make a thread to execute certain code every X seconds, in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I need to execute certain calls in a separate thread of my C# Net Core WebApi. I've been looking at some documentation but I didn't found anything that could fit my needs.

I have this code as my `Program.cs` (for testing porpouses) but I'ts not working:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace backend
{
    public class Program
    {
       
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(test);
            timer.Start();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            
        }
        public static void test(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Look mom, I'm on a thread.");

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

I'm kinda new and lost on this topic. Any tip or idea?

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Anu6is Thank you very much for pointing me on the right direction. I think this is the answer i need and the documentation I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked it out to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). I've created a Background Service and added to the services from Startup.cs.

For documentation:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            /*...*/
            services.AddHostedService<TimedBackgroundService>();
            /*...*/
        }
```

Program.cs

```
namespace backend
{
    public class Program
    {
       
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            
        }
        

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

TimedBackgroundService.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace backend
{
    public class TimedBackgroundService:IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger<TimedBackgroundService> _logger;
        private Timer _timer;
        public TimedBackgroundService(ILogger<TimedBackgroundService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {

            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm working on a background Service");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also just extend `BackgroundService` and then execute `while(true){ await Task.Delay(...); DoWork(); }`